# Dynamically add choices to pulldown MVC Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this code in HomeController that should return the last 6 rows.

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetOriginalIDs(string thisPWS)
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    var cat = (from c in _db.DWS_BactiBucket.OrderByDescending(x => x.SampDate) 
               where  c.PWS == thisPWS && c.SampType  == "R" && c.IsTOTPresent  == "1" select c).Take(6).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < cat.Length; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = cat[i].LabSampID + " (" + cat[i].SampDate + ")", Value = cat[i].LabSampID.ToString() });
    }

    return list
}
```

I want to run this code to populate a 2nd pulldown based on what was selected in the 1st pulldown(I'll bet you've never heard of this one before).

Here is the 1st pulldown on the Add View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @{
        var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="", Value=""});                
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="R", Value="R"});
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="P", Value="P"});                
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="C", Value="C"});
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="T", Value="T"});
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="A", Value="A"});   
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem{Text="S", Value="S"});                

        }

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SampType, listItems)

</div>
```

This all shows up fine and dandy.
Here is the second pulldown:

```
        <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OrigSampID(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Originals)
   })

         </div>
```

The goal is to populate the 2nd one using JSON and or jQuery but I cannot wrap my head around the code syntax for calling the controller and filling the 2nd pulldown. All examples have not helped me.

Comment: Whats the logic for populating the second one? Is it based on the selected value of the first one. Google [MVC cascading select](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mvc+cascading+select&oq=mvc+cascading+select&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0.7918j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). There are plenty of examples of how to do this

Comment: ok, I went to your google search and the first 8 links all deal with the same type of proof of concept State/City cascading pulldowns. It looks like the 9th one might get me going closer to what I want. But I am waiting to see what bigfetz says about my current code.

Comment: Not sure I understand your query. The first dropdown will have a value of "R" or "P" or "C" etc. Is that what you want to post back to `GetOriginalIDs`? So if you select "R" then the query would be `from c in _db.DWS_BactiBucket.OrderByDescending(x => x.SampDate) where c.PWS == "R" && c.SampType  == "R" && c.IsTOTPresent  == "1" select c ....`?  As for returning the JSON, you should create a list of anonymous objects with the value and text you want for the second dropdown (not a `SelectList`

Comment: If the value is "P", then populate the 2nd pulldown. (P means "repeat sample" which has to have an R (routine positive) referenced.
So I am putting off determing what value the 1st gets selected. I am assuming "P" so that I can get the hard part working first.
Well, I am trying out a "JsonResult" and placing the rows in a list and returning it as a result. But now I get this error.
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items
this is caused by the SelectItemList I am trying to populate.

Comment: I see you have posted another related question. I'll respond there.

Answer (score 1):

So if we have this html:

```
<select id="drop1">
  <option value="R">R</option>
  <option value="P">P</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="T">T</option>
</select>
<select id="drop2">
</select>
```

You could use this jquery to listen for the action of selecting the option

```
$('#drop1').change(function(){
   $.get('GetData', {value : $(this.val())}, function(json){
      var html = ''
      $(json).each(function() {
         html += '<option value="' + $(this).value  +'">' + $(this).text + ' '</option>'
      })
      $('#drop2').empty().append(html) //empty first then append to remove previous elements
   })
});
```

You could have a method in your controller call GetData like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetData(char val)
{
  //turn elements into json result
  return Json( elements);
}
```

Note: You could return a partial from the back end which would have the html constructed already and then append that to the dropdown, but I find it simpler just to create the options in the JS rather than having to create in the back end.

Comment: hey bigfetz it's looking close I'm thinking. However I get lost when I get to your controller code, because if you look at what I currently have in my first block of code (it builds a list from a database query, currently using a harcoded 99999). I am not sure how to do the "return Json(elements" part in your last block of code.

A water sample detection requires a repeat sample and the repeat must reference the ID of the original positive sample. 2nd pulldown returns last 6 positives for the entered water system ID, using it's ID.

Comment: Well my idea was you use the val(val would be the ID) in the parameter of GetData action, then do a query with val to get the elements from your database that you want to populate your dropdown list with. One way you could do this is create a array of SelectListItem's with the data you get from your query. Then put that into Json() and return it(yea its that simple). The json will then be available to the front end jquery to create the html that you populate the dropdown list with.

Comment: Also would like to note that you may get this exception when trying to get the Json :

"This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet."

Just add JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet like so : Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) to fix the error.